# Spring Clean-Up!

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, deleted-questions

I'm retaking this question and slightly change it to address a larger issue.

Since we don't want any [broken windows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broken_windows_theory) on our site, but only nice shiny questions, we are going to do some spring clean up and clean the site from bad/closed/etc questions.

---

### Start date

**2<sup>th</sup> March 2012**

From now on we will be grouping here questions that are:

- [eligible for deletion](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/287/111);
- eligible for merging;
- [eligible for closure](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/289/111) (and if not improved, consequently deleted);
- [eligible for migration](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/288/111) (and then deleted).

Into separated answers so you can easily browse them. I'm asking for **everyone** to help with this. It's not mandatory, I'm just asking it. :) But I hope you will! Simply add the question link to the list where it belongs.

If you fix a question from the lists we will have here, **flag it** so we can remove it from the list and "save" it.

If a question is reopened, remove it from the list.
If a question is deleted, use the tags `<s></s>` to apply a stroke.

**Note**: Please note that if questions get deleted, you will lose reputation if you posted an answer and received upvotes. If you lost reputation due to a deletion, please review the question, so it can be undeleted (you must be a high-rep user to see them though). If you don't have enough reputation, you can contact a moderator in chat. (I'm often there, just ping me by writing `@Alenanno`, if you start writing it, the system will auto-complete it for you.)

Answer (score 1):

### Eligible for deletion

1. [Translation of electrical connection gender names into non-Indo-European languages](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/483/111) 
   (has a reopen vote)
2. <s>[Which consonant is the diacritical aliph on in هَـٰذَا?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/1369/111)</s>
3. <s>[Is "Object name: quantity" notation acceptable in most popular languages?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/707/111)</s>
4. [What is the idea of ngram viewers working case-sensitive?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/842/111)
5. <s>[Looking for a language from Nigeria called “Urba”](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/1305/111)</s>
6. [Are there any papers about the calling contour (minor third, vocative chant) in Italian?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/1336/111) (reopened)
7. [What's the etymology of the Albanian word for hello, "tungjatjeta"?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/589/111)
8. <s>[Are modal particles (esp. fill-words) used frequently in many languages beside Japanese & German](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/782/111)</s>
9. <s>[sentence with different meaning in two languages?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/1379/111)</s>
10. <s>[Reference vs description](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/1446/111)</s>
11. <s>[Is there any connection between the semantic mapping of a language and the physiology of the language?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/1469/111)</s>
12. <s>[What are the associations emerging from the name “Waitu” or the suffix “tu” in different languages?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/1516/111)</s>

Comment: I have edited and retagged 1 and voted to reopen.

Comment: I have expanded 8 and voted to reopen.

Comment: @MarkBeadles Thank you for your contribution! :) I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

### Eligible for migration

1. [What are the rationale of people speaking/teaching Esperanto?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/354/111)
2. [is the percentage of people studying constructed languages increasing?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/1479/111)
3. [Is anyone studying change in constructed language?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/804/111)
4. [How did Esperanto find "early adopters" for the language?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/1912/111)
5. https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/1303/111
6. <s>https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/758/111</s>

Comment: Where would you migrate 1 to 3?

Comment: @kaleissin The conlang proposal when it goes into beta :)

Comment: @kaliessin and Alennano The conlang proposal is now dead. I suggest that we should re-examine 1, 2, 3 to see if they can be suitably edited and re-opened here.

Comment: On 6 why would you link to the English Language & Usage site for the question not the Linguistics site?

Answer (score 1):

### Eligible for closure

(if not improved after being closed, these ones will be deleted)

1. <s>https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/1503/111</s>
2. https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/1546/111
3. [Did case systems dissappear to make embedding easier?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/1548/111)
4. https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/1861/111

Comment: #2 currently has 4 upvotes, no downvotes, no close votes, and 2 upvoted answers, though none have been accepted. Seems like it should remain open at this time.

Comment: I have attempted to improve the title of #3, and I have provided an answer.

Comment: @MarkBeadles You're right about the second. I don't remember why it ended up there. I reopened it. About the third one, I'm not as sure, so I'd like people with high-reputation to vote to reopen, so I can see there is some will to reopen it.

Comment: There were no votes to close the third one, either, unless I'm not seeing something?

Comment: @MarkBeadles Ah I got it now. [Close votes expire if they don't arrive at a rate of at least one every 4 days](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97594/176533).

Comment: Aha, yes that would explain the strange things. So maybe this changes my view of #3 then. I will go take a further look.

Comment: Regarding #1, the questioner asked the [same question on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9459745/find-words-and-combinations-of-words-that-can-be-spoken-the-quickest) and accepted an answer there.

Comment: @MarkBeadles Thanks, I didn't notice that. The question has been closed.

Answer (score -1):

I have no objections to the closing and pruning of questions, and even I have been guilty of asking questions that had been closed. However, I do think that *now* is a very bad time to be doing the cleanup.

In light of the fact that [some SE sites are being closed down](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/326/sites-shutting-down-what-is-our-position/337#comment607_337) I have been looking at some [LinguisticsSE metrics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6673/linguistics). As per Area51 rules:

> 15 questions per day on average is a healthy beta, 5 questions or fewer per day needs some work.

Last week LinguisticsSE had **1.6** questions per day, two days ago it was **1.2** and today it is **1.1**. This site needs more questions, not less. Most of the other metrics are in need of improvement but questions/day is dire, we need an order of magnitude *more*.

**EDIT:** Note that I do *not* mean that LinguisticsSE should lower its standards. Rather, I mean that not closing or deleting questions could be an opportunity to broaden the site's scope of activity. Only keep quality questions that are borderline OT, don't keep low quality questions!

Comment: Actually this is not the place to be posting this answer, I thought you wanted to look at the material. But since you posted: It's always the time to cleanup. Longing for more questions doesn't mean, and *shouldn't* mean, lowering our standards. That way, the experts will go away or won't join at all. We must keep standards high, even if it means closing questions. One last thing, [don't confuse closing with deletion](http://meta.linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/248/111). :)

Comment: I understand what you mean, but this answer has no relation to the question that I asked in the comments of the "sites shutting down" thread. I apologise if it looks that way. I'm not pushing an agenda, or trolling!

Comment: I know you aren't! :D Don't worry... I think that it might be harder, but keeping our higher standards will pay off in the long run! :)

Comment: Afterthought: I am not suggesting that LinguisticsSE lower its standards, but rather broaden its scope. I will edit the answer to clarify this.